# Can't edit/work with compressed stylesheet (css) in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, edit

There are two stylesheets for Wordpress theme - Trending:

> style.dev.css (30kB) uncompressed ( „dev” means it’s for development).
>
> style.css (23kB) compressed.

Doesn’t matter which file I change in many variations and upload through FTP it doesn’t work! That means layout takes no changes. Edited CSS, uploaded to the server but no change is taken.

Tried out many ways –

> 1.edited „style.dev.css”, loaded it to the server (don’t work), then renamed to „style.css” (still don’t work).
>
> 2.after editing „style.dev.css” compressed it and then loaded to the server (don’t work), then renamed to „style.css” (still don’t work).
>
> 1. when both are on server, server chooses the dev version „style.dev.css”, when I delete it, server jumps to „style.css”.
> 2. tried to edit one of them and then send to server (there is still no chage in layout).

Please someone give me a hint where the problem could be?

I have no idea where the problem could be, searched for a solution like for 2 days already.
[Link](http://cfs-gometzlaville.fr/cfs/) to my site on which I'm working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your site is pointing to 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cfs-gometzlaville.fr/cfs/wp-content/themes/trending/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">` for its style, to replace the stylesheet you will need to rename the updated / modifed sheet AFTER you have named the orignal `style.css` to something like `style_orig.css` and then change the name of the updated / modifed file to `style.css`. Once you have done that you will need to **reset the cache** from any **caching plugins** that you use. If this still doesn't work **clear your browser cache**.

**EDIT**

If i change the `style.css` in the websites HTML to `style.dev.css` changes are made.

As an alternative maybe you should look at **Child Theme's** [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) as this will be much more manageable for you. All you will have to do is follow the instructions on the link and then copy and paste the `css` from your `dev.css` into the child themes `css` and it will override the parent styles.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it's a long path to the result.

Comment: Your welcome, what method did you use / could you marked as answered incase anyone else with this issue needs some help! Thanks :)

Comment: While I was working with Custom CSS plugin which overrides theme's stylesheets though I feel a little bit unsecure cause it's just a plugin but as long as it is working it is ok. Why I cant just delete one of CSS and from HTML pointing to the stylesheet that is left?

Comment: There are two issues with using a plugin to achieve CSS modification. The first is that if the plugin is deactivated the custom CSS will no longer work / potentially be lost. Second is that the Plugin may break with a future update of WordPress / Themes. If you have access to your site via FTP I would advise to use a Child Theme. To answer your question, if you then update your Theme, the default CSS file will overwrite the custom one; therefore losing all your modifications!

Answer (score 0):

The website is currently referencing `style.dev.css`, which doesn't exist. It could be a problem with some caching plugin.

Read [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens)